# What does this mean in Google Play Developer Console?

Tags: android, console

What does 50 / 111 mean in Google Play Developer Console?

This is the link where I uploaded a picture of it: http://postimg.org/image/ve0meq6d5/

Please note: descriptions are in german language there

Comment: May be active installation out of downloaded installation..!!

Comment: http://imgur.com/YG25c7k - Explanation is right there?

Comment: That means 111 people installed the app and (111-50=) 61 uninstalled the app?

Comment: @David Yes you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you hover mouse on "?" in title header it shows you `Current Installed/Total Installed`.

Current Installed : Number of unique active devices where the app is currently installed.

Total Installed : Total number of unique users who have ever installed this app on one or more of their devices.

Comment: That means 111 people installed the app and (111-50=) 61 uninstalled the app?

Comment: That means just now the app is installed on exactly 50 unique active devices, right? That means approx. the half of the users unistalled the app?

Answer (score 0):

The smaller front number are the current installations known to Google. The larger second number is the total of installations through the Play Store. I'm not sure whether these are for unique users or just the total of downloads.